# Opening a new link using submit button not anchor tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web

I need to be able to when the submit  button is clicked a new tab must be open 
based on the anchor link coming from the database. I have been struggling for hours.

this is my form

```
<form action="" method="POST">

<select name="name">

<option value="">Select Names</option>
<option value="1">Names</option>
</select>
<input type ="submit" name="submit" value="find random name">

</form>
```

Here is the php

```
    <?php 
    $query="SELECT * FROM names_table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1  ";
    $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if(!$result){echo "no results";}
    while($selected=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){


    $link=$selected['name'];

    echo  $ran_name= "<a href=$link target=\"_blank\">Click here</a>";
  ?>
```

// this code works but i dont want to be able to use Click here i want to be able to 
generate the results once the submit button is clicked , the submit button must open the new tab.I think javascript must be used but i dont know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be, something like this?

```
<?php
..
echo  $ran_name= "<script> document.location.href='".$link."';</script>";
..
?>
```

More about location object http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp.

Comment: is there a way to open in a new tab? not a new window?

Comment: Ok, if you need this, use `action=""` in your form (for example `<form action="/worker.php" method="POST">`).
In a way, when you click on submit-button, your browser redirect you on a handler of form in new tab, wich you use in `action=""`. After that, you can execute your php code and have you page in new tab ;)

Comment: i do have action="" i meant sorry , i need it to open either in a new tab or a new window, that replaces the current document

Comment: i tried window.open but it appears as a popup and its blocked

Comment: Right, because you also need a `target="_blank"` attribute :) Finally you have `<form action="/worker.php" method="POST" target="_blank">` This must work ;)

Comment: You are the man!. Is it possible to open this within a page of my own? like i have my header on top but the body contain someone else's website.

Answer (score 0):

1. Way 1

   < input type="button" value="Open Window"

   onclick="window.open('< ?php echo $link;?>')">

OR:

```
onclick="window.location.href='< ?php echo $link;?>','_blank'";
```

2. Way 2:

   < form action="< ?php echo $link;?>" method="post" target="_blank">

   ```
   ...
   ```

   < /form>

p/s: I don't know how to show code with format. (same you);

Answer (score 0):

maybe you try this one? that's should do what you want

```
<?php 
    $query="SELECT * FROM names_table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1  ";
    $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if(!$result) {
      exit("no results");
    }
    while($selected=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){   
         $link=$selected['name'];
    }

    // Redirect to page
    if (defined($link) && !empty($link)) 
       header("Location: /$link");
  ?>
```